# google form inside a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, google-forms

I want to embad a google form to a wordpress page.
I tried to use the plug of word press of google form,

however the plug is does not support a multi questions.

this is how it looks in google form
[image]

and this is how it looks in wordpress

[image]

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the link of your google form in your website?